# Flexible Job Shop with Preemption

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, solver, scheduling, simulated-annealing

I'm trying to solve a flexible job shop problem variant that has precedence constraints on jobs along with a few other issues. We have a MIP formulation and also a simulated annealing algorithm to solve at the moment.  But now we would like to allow preemption of jobs (leaving a job and coming back to finish it later, possibly times).
Do you have any thoughts on how to model the problem to allow for preemption?

Comment: Would you please, what you mean by `how to model the problem to allow for preemption`? Would you need to model it in the MP or by using the SA algorithm? In the first case, there are lots of papers to do that.

Comment: Are there complications such as tear-down and set-up costs for each preemption, or periods during a job when preemption is not allowed

Comment: Sorry for the radio silence.  Yes, I'm looking for a model for the MP.   Lots of papers you say?   Can you point me to one?   Is there a nice technique to allow for continuous time preemption of a job?  The tricky part here for me seems to be that the scenario I have in mind, there is a time cost of moving from one job to another.  So in this sense, it is unclear how many times you would need to move from one job to another with preemption is allowed.  Furthermore, we may need multiple machines to work on a job together, so coordinating them seems tricky.